# Relinking Container Files in Filemaker

Tags: json, database, image, containers, filemaker

I imported a load of images of books ive been using for research into my database. they are stored on my mac in a folder called BOOK IMAGES IMPORT > BookTitle > page#.jpg Once I imported the images into the database i set it up that the images would be stored externally(open). Later in the day I made a new database file and deleted the table that housed the container field. I later went back to my earlier version but found that the external storage for the book images has gone (because I deleted the table earlier). I had the file paths for the images saved in a field next to the container field, the file path locating them to this folder BOOK IMAGES IMPORT > BookTitle > page#. I wrote a script that looked like this

Go to Record/Request/Page [ First ]

Loop

Set Variable [ $filePath ; Value: BookPages::FilePath ]

Set Field [ BookPages::Image ; BookPages::FilePath ]

Insert Picture [ “$filepath” ]

Commit Records/Requests [ With dialog: Off ]

Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next ; Exit after last: On ]

End Loop

and now the container displays page#.jpg whereas before I ran that script it displayed "missing file". However, the image is not displayed, only the jpg icon with the page name beneath. When I double click in the container field the image opens in preview. I've tried clearing my cache, exporting the records and opening in a new database. I tried dragging and dropping an image into the database and that worked, and it created a file in the external(open) storage folder, which otherwise does not exist. I've tried to toggle on and off the external storage option as I feel like this may is part of the problem. I've cleared the cache too, and have got as far as I. an with troubleshooting with ChatGPT. Can anyone help?

It seems totally bonkers that filemaker wouldn't be able to make it possible to relink container files with a file path, surely if InDesign can do it then filemaker must be able to too?

I'm UK based so holding out hope that some American's can help me over night!

Comment: What happens if you do: `Set Variable [ $filePath ; Value: "image:" & BookPages::FilePath ]`, `Go to Field [ BookPages::Image ]`, `Insert Picture [ "$filePath" ]`?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `json`?

Comment: @ michael.hor257k  if i run the script with your edit I get error message"The file “63.JPG” could not be found and is required to complete this operation." but when i double click the icon in the field though the image opens in preview

Comment: @ y.arazim because the script language in filemaker is json

Comment: The error suggests you do **not** have the correct path to the original image in the  `BookPages::FilePath` field, contrary to what you said in your question (or you did not implement my suggestion correctly). Still, if double-clicking the `BookPages::Image` field opens the (original) file, you should be able to get the path from there, by using `GetAsText(BookPages::Image)` (do all your experiments on a copy, so that you do not permanently overwrite the working paths).

Comment: P.S. Filemaker's scripting language is **not** JSON. JSON is not even a scripting language as such. It's a data *format*. --- PP.S. When you put a space between @ and the user's name, then the user does not get notified. I saw your comment by sheer accident

Comment: Fixed my problem using the code below
Go to Record/Request/Page [ First ]
Loop
Set Field [ BookPages::Container ; Base64Decode ( Base64Encode ( BookPages::Container ) ; GetContainerAttribute ( BookPages::Container ; "FileName" )) ] 
Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next ; Exit after last: Off ]
End Loop
Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, that makes very little sense to me - but then so does the original description. I suggest you delete your question since it's not likely to help anyone else.